# Is this definition of limit at infinity of complex functions correct?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, definition, infinity

In my book (*Churchill*), a limit of a function at infinity is defined as:
$$  \lim\limits_{z \to \infty}f(z) \equiv \lim\limits_{z \to 0}f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) $$

But why can't you define the point at infinity as $|z|>\alpha, \forall\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$? So you would get:

$$  \lim\limits_{z \to \infty}f(z) \equiv \lim\limits_{|z| \to \infty}f(z) $$

If this equivalence can be made, could you give me some hints to prove it? (I think it should be something like  $\lim\limits_{|r| \to \infty}f(re^{i\theta})$ is independent of $\theta$).

I think this way would be more natural and similar to real analysis.

Comment: The two are equivalent. $\lvert z\rvert > \alpha \iff \left\lvert \frac1z\right\rvert < \frac1\alpha$ (for $\alpha > 0$).

Comment: Aside: what you are defining is not the "point at infinity", but instead a system of punctured neighborhoods of infinity. I.e. this collection of sets relates to $\infty$ in the same way that the collection of sets $0 < |z| < \epsilon$ relate to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Your definition works.  You could also say that $\lim_{z\to\infty} f(z) = l$
if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is some compact $K \subset \mathbb{C}$ so that
$z\not\in K\implies |f(z) - l| < \epsilon$.

Comment: How can a prove that $ \lim\limits_{|r| \to \infty}f(re^{i\theta})=l $ is independent of $\theta$ so both definitions are equivalent?